# Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a JS error on displaying a page: Nothing concrete is specified but the line where it seems to be thrown. When looking into the source code of the page, I see the error is thrown inside the following script, but I can't understand why! It's only about loading images!

```
    <SCRIPT language=JavaScript>
<!--
function newImage(arg) {
    var rslt = new Image();
    rslt.src = arg;
    return rslt;
}
function changeImages(a, b) {
    a.src = b;
}
newImage("\/_layouts\/images\/icon1.gif");
newImage("\/_layouts\/images\/icon2.gif");
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

The error I am getting is when clicking on a drop down context menu on a page, for this line:

```
newImage("\/_layouts\/images\/icon1.gif");
```

> The object doesn't accept this property or method
>   Code: 0

I really don't see what could happen... Any tips on what may be happening here?

Comment: can you include the rest of the script that's causing the error?

Comment: You are going to have to give more information :)

Comment: Please post the rest of the offending script.

Comment: What is the error message, and which of the lines above does it point to?

Comment: <!-- --> is a comment block so it's possible that the code isn't actually even firing so the calling code will be firing a not found error?

Comment: Definitely could use at least one of the error messages.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried loading your scripts into a JS debugger such as [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) or Firefox plugin like [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843)?

Comment: THe comments are ok, these are HTML comments, not JS. Thats an archaic way not to break old browsers.

Comment: True - for some reason when I read the code I read it to have the <!-- before the <script> tag

Answer (score 2):

Why are you escaping the forward slashes. That's not necessary. The two lines should be:

```
newImage("/_layouts/images/icon1.gif");
newImage("/_layouts/images/icon2.gif");
```

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to answer your question with the limited information provided:

1. You are not showing the complete script
2. You never said what the exact error message is, or even what browser is giving the error.
3. Which line number is the error supposedly coming from?

I'd recommend using Firebug in firefox for debugging javascript if you aren't already.  IE tends to give bogus line numbers.

And as others have already said, the language attribute for script tags is deprecated.

Comment: The error has been updated, the complete script is there too :-(

Answer (score 1):

Write proper xml with the " around attributes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newImage(arg) {
    var rslt = new Image();
    rslt.src = arg;
    return rslt;
}
function changeImages(a, b) {
    a.src =     b;
}
newImage("/_layouts/images/icon1.gif");
newImage("/_layouts/images/icon2.gif");
</script>
```

Comment: ...except SCRIPT isn't an xhtml attribute, script is. And there's no language attribute on script in xhtml.

Comment: of course since she ommited anything that indicates weather she does SGML or XML it's a tad hard to do it precisely right

Answer (score 0):

should your script block not be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

?

Answer (score 0):

For starters, start your script block with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Not

```
<script language=JavaScript>
```

That's probably not the root of your problem, but since we can't see your script, that's about all we can offer.

Comment: For some reason, all the scripts in that page have 'language' instead of 'type'. What's the actual difference?

Comment: "language" is the old style; in XHTML, you use "type", and you refer to it as "text/javascript"

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enlist the help of a Javascript debugger. I've never figured out how to make the various debuggers for IE work, so I can't help you if you're using IE.

If you're using Firefox or you CAN use Firefox, make sure you have a Tools / Javascript Debugger command. (If you don't, reinstall it and be sure to enable that option.) Next, open up the debugger, rerun the problem page, and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling changeImages?  It looks as though you are not saving a reference to the images returned by newImage.  You probably want to save the results of newImage and pass that to the changeImages routine.  Then changeImages should look like this:

```
function changeImages(a, b) {
    a.src = b.src;
}
```

You also may want to ensure that the images have finished loading before calling changeImages.

You've posted the routine that throws the error, without posting the error or showing us how you are calling it.  If none of the answers posted fix your problem then please post some detail about how you are calling the method, which specific line the error is on, and what the error message is.

Answer (score 0):

You firebug to debug.
http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/products/download.html?product=firefox-3.0.10&os=win&lang=en-US
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843

JSLint is also a nice resource.
http://www.jslint.com/

Using CDATA instead of the `<!-- // -->`
http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_cdata.asp

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
]]>
</script>
```